# Way to convert if-else statement into one-liner

Tags: python

Is there a way to do the following on one line?

```
if completion.is_anonymous:
    user = 'Anonymous'
else:
    user = completion.user
```

Comment: It surprises me that you have ~9k reputation but the thought of googling this simple task didn't cross your mind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use ternary operators:

```
user = 'Anonymous' if completion.is_anonymous else completion.user
```

Answer (score 0):

There is the `user = "Anonymous" if completion.is_anonymous else completion.user` syntax:

```
>>> a = 2 if True else 4
>>> a
2
>>> a = 2 if False else 4
>>> a
4
```